# C# how to change bitmap image color and apply anti-aliasing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oop, antialiasing

I am working on a flowchart making application and it involves changing the color of images with transparency(png). I've been searching for hours about workarounds and it's either that it's not what I'm looking for or I can't make it work.

First, let me show you the codes and how I do it. I removed the parts of the code that are unrelated to the question.

This is the class where I "create" the flowchart symbols. I inherited the Label class because I need text centered on the symbols. I use images in .png format located inside my Resources folder and change their color according to what the user wants.

```
namespace PF2
{
    public class Terminal : Label
    { 
            public void createTerminal(int x)
            {
                this.Width = 250;
                this.Height = 100;
                this.Name = "Terminal" + x;
                this.AutoSize = false;

                Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.shapeTerminal, new Size(this.Width, this.Height));
                this.Image = Globals.ChangeColor(resized, Color.Yellow);

                this.Text = this.Name;
                this.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            }
     }

}
```

Here is the color changing algorithm I use (found this on stackoverflow as well):

```
namespace PF2
{
    public static class Globals
    {
        public static Bitmap ChangeColor(Bitmap scrBitmap, Color newColor)
        {
            Color actualColor;
            Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(scrBitmap.Width, scrBitmap.Height);
            for (int i = 0; i < scrBitmap.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < scrBitmap.Height; j++)
                {
                    actualColor = scrBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                    if (actualColor.A > 150)
                        newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
                    else
                        newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, actualColor);
                }
            }
            return newBitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, how I call my class on my form

```
int x = 0;
private void btnTerminal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Terminal newSymbol = new Terminal();

    newSymbol.createTerminal(x);
    newSymbol.Parent = tabPage1;

    newSymbol.Location = new Point(newSymbol.Width * x + 4, 0);
    x++;
}
```

This is how my image looks like whenever I **don't** apply the color changing algorithm. It just sets the default image located in my Resources folder.

[Algo not applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1KPX.jpg)

This is how my image looks like whenever I apply the color changing algorithm. I want to apply anti-aliasing to make the edges look smooth like the original but I don't know how.

[Algo applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XsHr.jpg)

I stumbled upon  Interpolation while working on this but I can't make it work either. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem with minimal changes in the code. Any alternative ways would be good as well as long as it doesn't involve 3rd party software. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you considered just drawing your shapes as shapes (rather than as images) using GDI+ methods like `Graphics.FillPath()`?

Comment: Also, it's pretty clear where you're losing the antialiasing in the `ChangeColor` method: `if (actualColor.A > 150)`.  Also, `GetPixel()/SetPixel()` is going to be slow compared to a solution using `LockBits()`.

Comment: Yes, I did but I'm not sure if it can cover other symbols like Input/Output. Sorry, I used the color changing algo with little knowledge about it.

Comment: I think you'll have much better luck with `Graphics.FillPath()` and its friends.  Just spend some time reading the documentation for [the Graphics class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You can't really retrofit anti-aliasing as you would need to know about the 'correct' shape, i.e. the shape in a higher resolution than the pixel grid. Create it in GDI+ - not really hard and much more flexible..

Comment: Agree with adv12, 1) Create a bitmap, draw a rounded rectangle, add the text. It will also be much faster

Comment: Thanks, I'll research about both of your recommendations. Sorry, for this wall of text.